# NavigationLink's destination view doesn't update when variables change

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm experiencing strange behavior in SwiftUI and I am unsure whether this is a bug (I'm running Big Sur and XCode 12 beta) or I'm just doing it wrong.

When I pass a variable to a destination view of a `NavigationLink`, that destination view is not re-rendered when the variable changes. I've isolated this behavior to show you. This is a fully working example (only working with the new SwiftUI version and iOS 14):

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var name: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List {
                
                NavigationLink(destination: MasterView(name: name)) {
                    Text("Show Name In Big")
                }
                
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 1)
                
                Text("Current Name: \(name)")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                
                Button(action: {
                    name = "Doug"
                }, label: {
                    Text("Change Name")
                        .bold()
                })
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            
            Text("Master")
            Text("Detail")
        }
        
    }
}

struct MasterView: View {
    let name: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
            .font(.title)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(name: "Bob")
    }
}
```

And here is a short gif demonstrating the behavior (sorry for the bad resolution, here's a video with a better resolution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aTCex86tkYQ):

[image]

Is this intended behavior?

EDIT:

A simple example to demonstrate that you don't need a `Binding` for a view to be rerendered on value change:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    
    @State var someVariable: String = "Old Value"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(someVariable)
            SubView(someVariable: someVariable) // initialized without Binding
            
            Button("Click to update variable") {
                someVariable = "New Value"
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    
    let someVariable: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(someVariable)
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

use `@Binding` for `name` in `MasterView`:

```
@Binding var name : String
```

And, pass `name` like:

```
NavigationLink(destination: MasterView(name: $name)) {
...
}
```

Now, when your `state`(name) is changed, other views(are using that state as `Binding`) will be notified.

Comment: Sorry if I'm mistaken, but shouldn't it also work without `@Binding`? I don't need to be able to change `name` inside `MasterView`, so `@Binding` wouldn't be appropriate (following Apple's best practices). If I add `MasterView(name: name)` in my sidebar List (simply add it below the NavigationLink or so) then that view updates fine when the variable changes, even without `@Binding`

Comment: I don't understand why the view should be updated without property wrapper. maybe there are some concepts I don't know.

Comment: @Quantm the provided answer is absolutely right. NavigationLink in SwiftUI is non-lazy link to a view. So the init method is ran even if you didn't actually click the link. Thus it works differently from the case you described.

Comment: The @Binding just gives you the possibility to write back to the original variable of some parent view. Even without it SwiftUI will re-render child views that use a variable that has changed.

Comment: @bde.dev okay thanks. But this seems to be strange. So you are forced to use a Binding? Even for simple views that don’t need that? That would go against Apple‘s own guidelines, I think

Comment: @bde.dev wait, but this shouldn’t be the case, even if it isn’t lazy. Every time a state changes, the body is recomputed and I know that the initializer of `MasterView` is actually called again. And I think that’s exactly what’s supposed to happen. Just its content doesn’t change at all. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: I believe to have pointed you in the right direction. You can see for yourself by putting print statement in the init function. Then change your state and play around you'll best understand how the state of the child view works by monitoring these print statements.

Comment: @Quantm The Binding is not only for writing back to the original variable. It is also used to notify its own view to re-render itself. whats your solution if you need a view without changing the variables and re-rendering the view?

Comment: @FRIDDAY yes, but that notification can also be triggered by a parent view. If the parent view changes, it redraws its content, thus also the simple child view. See https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation, the struct LandmarkRow does exactly this. It relies on its parent view to update it

Comment: @Quantm the example you mentioned is just for displaying items and there is no button or anything else to change state of variables.

Comment: @FRIDDAY I've added an example to the question. Even if you're just displaying items, they still have to be correct and true to the data model. See my example, please try and run it (you don't need any beta software for this example). The notification about a variable change comes from `TestView`. This triggers a recomputation of its `body` property. This will literally rerun the Code inside `TestView`s `body` and thus reinitialize `SubView` with the newly changed variable.

Comment: @Quantm I got it. looks like a bug to me. So the first one should be working. For now I can just say it works in this case, but not in the other one :). If it is not consider a bug. And it seems you have only `Binding` option for now.

Comment: @FRIDDAY Okay, thanks. Appreciate your help! I'm going to file a bug report, then we'll see

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug with `List` in SwiftUI. If you replace `List` with `VStack` in your code, it should start working fine. I've yet to come up with a work-around for this. Let me know if you have heard back from Apple in the bug report filing.